# friend function in C++ is not accessing private members

Tags: c++, friend-function

I am learning C++ and I have written the below given simple program to understand the working of friend function
(ignore all the complication I made by using complex syntax in the code because I am learning and I practice the syntax that I learn in programs).

The `friend` function is not accessing the private members of `test` and `stu`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

class test;

class stu
{
    private:
        int z;
    public:
        stu(int z)
        {
            this->z=z;
        }
    
        friend disp(stu,test);
        
        ~stu(void)
        {
            std::cout<<"Destructor of stu class is executed!!"<<std::endl;
        }
        
};

class test{
    private:
        int x;
    public:
        test(int a)
        {
            x=a;
        }
        
        friend disp(stu,test);
        
        ~test(void)
        {
            std::cout<<"Destructor is executed!!"<<std::endl;
        }
    
};

class test2:public test
{
    private:
        int b;
    public:
        test2(int b)
        {
            this->b=b;
        }
        
        void show(void);
        
        ~test2(void)
        {
            std::cout<<"Destructor of second class executed!!"<<std::endl;
        }
};


int main()
{
    test t1(3);
    test2 t2(5);
    t2.show();
    stu s1(10);
    disp(s1,t1);
    
    return 0;
}

void test2::show(void)
{
    std::cout<<"Value of k = "<<b<<std::endl;
}

void disp(stu s2, test t2)
{
    int sum;
    sum = s2.z + t2.x;
    std::cout<<"Sum  =  "<<sum<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: *"The friend function is not accessing the private members of test and stu."* - can you elaborate on this?  e.g. is this causing a compile error, a runtime error, unexpected behavior, etc?  Also I'd recommend reducing this code down into a [mcve].

Comment: Your `friend disp(stu, test);` lines should be `friend void disp(stu, test);` ... and you'll be needing a default constructor for `test`.

Comment: @0x5453 yeah it is giving multiple errors like (1)[Error] no matching function for call to 'test::test()'   (2) [Error] ambiguating new declaration of 'void disp(stu&, test&)'    (3)[Note] test::test(int)  (4) [Note] candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided  (5)[Note] test::test(const test&) and both the variables are privates and are declared outside the scope of it

Comment: @Adrian Mole  thanks  now only the error 1 2 3 4 and 5 that i have mentioned here are remaining

Comment: One question at a time, man.

Comment: You will find the [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) helpful.

Comment: @user4581301 hahaha ok

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the `disp` function before the `main` function :

```
void disp(stu s2, test t2)
{
    int sum;
    sum = s2.z + t2.x;
    std::cout<<"Sum  =  "<<sum<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    test t1(3);
    test2 t2(5);
    t2.show();
    stu s1(10);
    disp(s1,t1);
    
    return 0;
}
```

and change the `disp` function signature as:

```
friend void disp(stu,test);
```

Comment: Thanks mate not writing the return type was a mistake and but these error are not going away and i dont understand why because i have already provided the arguments                                                                                                                                           In constructor 'test2::test2(int)':
[Error] no matching function for call to 'test::test()'
[Note] candidates are:
[Note] test::test(int)
[Note] candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
[Note] test::test(const test&)
[Note] candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided